# passing 2d array to a function | passing argument 1 of ‘function’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I am passing 2d array to a function, But its giving me error that `passing argument 1 of ‘jac’ from incompatible pointer type`

this is how I created the array

```
double t[m+2][n+2];
....
jac(t);
printf("*should print what assigned in jac function %f\n",t[0][0]);
```

in called function I am doing like this

```
void jac(double **tnew)
{
   tnew[0][0]=tnew[2][1]+tnew[0][1];

}
```

why its giving me warning that `passing argument 1 of ‘jac’ from incompatible pointer type`

Comment: I need to know if I have declared variable like this `double t[m+2][n+2];` then how to pass it to function. best would be if parameter signature is some pointer

Comment: You can use `void jac(int m, int n, double tnew[m+2][n+2])`. NOTE: `t` is a *Variable Length Array* so you will need to provide at minimum the dimension for the last `[..]`. Your array has type `double (*)[n+2]` (pointer-to-array-of `double[n+2]`) Not type `double **` (pointer-to-pointer-to `double`) Also type `"[c] passing 2d array"` into the search box above.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what variable size array means. Can u please explain I  simple words

Comment: `double **` and `double [m+2][n+2]` are two different, incompatible types.

Comment: What about double[][] and (*)[] are they compatible?

Comment: There is no such thing as `double[][]`, you need an actual size in there (at least in the rightmost brackets).

Comment: An array, on access, is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. In C, a 2D array is an *array of arrays* (e.g. a 1D array of arrays). Declaring `double t[x][y]` declares a 2D VLA. On access `t` is converted to a pointer to the first element of `t` (which is another 1D array of size `y` here). So the type is `double (*)[y]`. You can also write the type without applying the conversion to pointer as `double [x][y]`. You can use either. You can omit `x`, but must provide the final dimension `y`, so `double[][y]` is also fine. None of which is `double **`.